# Vhdl ERROR that I don't understand

Tags: vhdl

I have a problem with my vhdl code . In active-hdl it works perfectly , but when i tried to implement it on the FPGA board using ise design xilinx i have a problem with one component . The error i found is:

> ERROR:Xst:827 - "E:/proiect_final/dispozitiv_impartitor/src/generator_square_wave.vhd" line 16: Signal numar_intermediar<0> cannot be synthesized, bad synchronous description. The description style you are using to describe a synchronous element (register, memory, etc.) is not supported in the current software release.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity generator_square_wave is 
    port(clock,reset :in bit;
        controler:std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        numar:out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        data_clock:out bit);
end generator_square_wave ;

architecture descriere of generator_square_wave  is
signal reset1:std_logic;
begin
        process (clock,reset) -- here it shows me the error 
        variable numar_intermediar:bit_vector(3 downto 0 ):="0000";
    variable numar_intermediar2:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    variable bitul:bit;
    begin
        reset1<=to_stdulogic(reset);
            if rising_edge(reset1) then
                numar_intermediar:="0001";  
            numar_intermediar2:=To_StdLogicVector(numar_intermediar);
            numar(0)<=numar_intermediar2(0);
            numar(1)<=numar_intermediar2(1);
            numar(2)<=numar_intermediar2(2);
            numar(3)<=numar_intermediar2(3);
            numar(4)<='0';
            numar(5)<='0';
            numar(6)<='0';
            numar(7)<='0';

        else if( clock'event and clock ='1' and controler="001")then
                bitul:=numar_intermediar(0);
            numar_intermediar:=numar_intermediar srl 1;
            numar_intermediar(3):=bitul;
            numar_intermediar2:=To_StdLogicVector(numar_intermediar);
            numar(0)<=numar_intermediar2(0);
            numar(1)<=numar_intermediar2(1);
            numar(2)<=numar_intermediar2(2);
            numar(3)<=numar_intermediar2(3);
            numar(4)<='0';
            numar(5)<='0';
            numar(6)<='0';
            numar(7)<='0';
        if(reset/='1' and controler/="001")then
            numar<="00000000";
        end if;
    end if;
    end if;
            data_clock<=clock;
        end process;
end descriere;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems. First, you shouldn't be treating reset as a clock (i.e. using `rising_edge()`). If it's asynchronous, you should just write:

```
if reset1 = '1' then
  ...
```

The following line also has a problem (not sure if this is strictly illegal, but it's not recommended):

```
if( clock'event and clock ='1' and controler="001")then
```

This should be:

```
if clock'event and clock = '1' then
  if controler = "001" then
```

(with additional `end if` to match.)

That should at least allow it to synthesize.

You may also want to make the statement `reset1<=to_stdulogic(reset)` concurrent instead of including it in the process, and there are a couple other possible changes you could make, but they're not as critical (unless I've missed something).

Comment: Thank you fru1tbat. I have one more question if you don`t mind. Somewhere in the code, at this line there is another error that I don`t get:    if(data_clock'event and data_clock='1')then -- ERROR:HDLCompiler:76 -  Line 31: statement is not synthesizable since it does not hold its value under NOT(clock-edge) condition

Comment: I didn't notice that you were assigning `data_clock` inside your process. You should make that statement concurrent as well.

Comment: Could you tell me in general what this error should mean? Because I have this error inside another component of my vhdl code. Again, this code works on VHDL, the problem that I think it might ve is that this is an error regarding Suite ISE. I also used rising_edge,but that didn`t solve my problem (SAME ERROR)

Comment: I'd have to see your code to be sure exactly what the error is (maybe you could add it to your question). It's almost certainly not a "problem" with ISE itself, though. Simulators are much more forgiving than synthesis tools, because they don't have to worry about inferring actual physical logic - they just run what you tell them to. There are many places you can find guides on coding styles for synthesis - I will post one here if I get a chance to look one up.

Comment: Under [ISE Help](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/isehelp_start.htm "ISE Help"), Documentation Overview, User Guides, there are two PDF XST user guides covering different device families. They are organized differently but both describe VHDL constructs recognized for synthesis.  There should be an ISE Help with your ISE distribution.